# Making a logo afraid of the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to create a logo that "runs away" from the mouse on my header.  I can get the right side working but I cannot manage to accomplish the same functionality on the left!  I am not worried about the logo going off screen that is okay, but I do want the mouse to be able to move the logo over from the left or the right!

Currently I have an if statement detecting which div side you are approaching the logo from but it only works when approaching from the right, the left doesn't seem to work, I think it could be some binding issue with the mouse-over event but I am knew to this and don't fully understand what that means.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boundary').mouseover(slide);
  
  $("#logo").mouseenter(function() {
        $('.boundary').unbind("mouseover");
    });
    $("#logo").mouseleave(function() {
        $('.boundary').mouseover(slide);
    });
});

function slide() {
  var leftWidth = parseInt($('#left').css('width'));
  
var calculatedWidthL = leftWidth - 100 + "px";
var calculatedWidthL2 = leftWidth + 100 + "px";
  
  var rightWidth = parseInt($('#right').css('width'));
  
var calculatedWidthR = rightWidth - 100 + "px";
var calculatedWidthR2 = rightWidth + 100 + "px";
  
    if ($("#logo")) $("#logo").animate({
      
        left: $(this).is('#left')?"+=100px":"-=100px"
    }, "fast");
  
 if($("#right")){
   $("#right").width(calculatedWidthR2); 
   $("#left").width(calculatedWidthL); 
    }
  else if($("#left")){
   $("#left").width(calculatedWidthL2); 
   $("#right").width(calculatedWidthR); 
    }
    
    
    $('.boundry').unbind("mouseover");
}
```

```css
.boundary{
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:relative;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
}

.logo1{
  position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin-top: -50px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -50px; /* Half the width */
}


#left{
    left:0px;
}
#right{
    right:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="container">
<img id="logo" class="logo1" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/letter-j-icon-png-24.png">
  
  <div id="skinDiv">
    <div id="left" class="boundary"></div>
    <div id="right" class="boundary"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sidenote, `$('.boundry').mouseover(slide);` - missing an a